# MySQL - DATEDIFF LOOKUP previous row (same ID)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an extra column on my SQL where I could identify if the user_id generated a subsequent (or even third) row.

And if so, calculate the datediff between the connection time and previous row disconnection time.

If no duplicate user_id, the response should be NULL.

Here's a screenshot of my data and notes:

[image]

I tried the DATEDIFF formula but no success.

Could someone help me on this? I really would appreciate any input.

```
SELECT id,
user_id,
connected_at,
disconnected_at,

IFNULL(DateDiff('second', Lookup(disconnected_at), -1), connected_at)

FROM data
ORDER BY id, user_id, connected_at
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

When comparing values in different rows, you need to join the table to itself to get the second row. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.user_id,
    a.connected_at,
    a.disconnected_at,
    DateDiff('second',b.`connected_at`,a.`disconnected_at`) as `time_diff`
FROM `data` a
JOIN `data` b
ON a.`user_id` = b.`user_id` AND b.`connected_at` > a.`disconnected_at`
```